# Prolem in invoking a shell script in container through Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am very new in Docker. I am using Centos. My use case in I have a folder in my /opt/abc/Myfolder.Also the /opt/abc/Myfolder contains a script xyz.sh, which is a kind of application running as say localhost:7575
I want Myfolder to get copied in /usr/local/ of my container and to run the shell script xyz.sh when I start my image. I am using centos:7 as base image.

Following is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y && \
yum install -y wget && \
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel && \
yum clean all

ADD ./MyFolder /usr/local/MyFolder

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /

CMD ["/usr/local/MyFolder/xyz.sh"]
```

The image got build. When I run the image no error came up. But script didn't run.
Can anyone please guide where I am going wrong.
Maybe I should use RUN or ENTRYPOINT in such cases.

Comment: What happens now?

Comment: The image got build. When I run the image no error came up. But script didn't run.

Comment: What _does_ happen?  Sharing your actual `docker run` command and the contents of the script might help debug further.

Comment: did you try CMD [ "sh","/usr/local/MyFolder/xyz.sh"] ??(or bash)